# Deploying and implementing new features on websites

Tags: web-applications, deployment

I recently launched my first serious website that I've been working on for the past six month. I have some general questions regarding maintenance of the site and implementing new features.

For instance, let's say I want to add a form on the index page where the users can submit feedback to me. Where would I write this form during development? I mean, I can't develope on the page that is currently online and accessable for visitors. Should I copy my entire site and put it somewhere else where I develope and then replace the online version with my new? Are there any programs made for this where you can keep versions of your site and deploy them? How do big sites tackle this?

I'll mention that I use PHP, although the question is not associated with any particular language. Please share articles and other information sources that bring this topic into focus if you know any.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A short answer for you:  source control.

Most software (not just web) professionals use some kind of source control system (like Git, SVN, etc.) to store "the" copy of their working software, develop in some form of development environment (on local Apache, etc.) - then use a checkout from the source repository onto their "production" server, or just FTPing/transferring a clean copy of your working site to your web server.

(Version control software also keeps histories, versions and the ability to roll back versions when needed.  If you want a free playground, sign up for an account at http://github.com )